# Split numbers using comma

Tags: java

[image]I have a list of numbers which is  formatted as 106,648|403,481 in a file .I have to add all Second coordinate Of this list and need the sum.I am able to split this list using the | but when i try to split them using , its not working .This i have done so far,. Please someone help me ...

```
package org.jeet.App;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;



public class MidPointSum {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    File file = new File("D:/midpoint.txt");

    try {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

        while (sc.hasNext()) {

            String value = sc.next();



            int myint[] = new int[2];

            String[] tokens = value.split("\\|");


            for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {




                System.out.println(tokens[i]);
                //System.out.println(charSplit[i]);
            }

        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("File is not Found");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Another Exception");
    }

}
}
```

plese help  me to split numbers as
106 648
403 481
.. 
and so on

Comment: and want output  106 648     403 481 and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would split on *either* pipe or comma and take every odd-numbered element:

```
String[] tokens = value.split("[|,]");
for (int i = 1; i < tokens.length - 1; i += 2) {
    System.out.println(tokens[i]);
}
```

Comment: +1, the efficient way, only one split!

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `split()` again with ",". To get everything neatly in an `ArrayList` you can do it like this:

```
ArrayList<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
for(String token : value.split("\\|"))
{
    for(String subToken : token.split(","))
    {
        tokens.add(subToken);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] tokens = value.split("\\|"); 
for (String token: tokens) {
      String[] subTokens = value.split(","); 
      System.out.println(subTokens[0]); // This is your first 
      System.out.println(subTokens[1]); // This is your second
}
```